# can not find ssh interpereter in pycharm

Tags: ssh, pycharm, interpreter

[image]

I want to add ssh interpreter at pycharm,
but I can't find it.
what's the reason? and How can I fix it?

[image]

this is the version of my pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH-based interpreters are supported in PyCharm Professional Edition only. See the comparison matrix https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html